# Localization does not work on main activity

Tags: android, android-activity, localization

I have implemented a localization in my app for Croatian and English language. The user can chanage the language in the `PreferenceActivity`.

This is the code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {...}
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
          if (key.equals("language")) {
            String language= sharedPreferences.getString(key, "1");
            if (language.equals("2")) {
                    switchLang("en");
            } else {
                    switchLang("hr");
            }
          }

   }

   private void switchLang(String langCode) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(langCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    onCreate(null);
   }
}
```

And I have in my res folder a structure like this:

[image]

In the folders drawable-en-hdpi and drawable-hr-hdpi are images with the same names of course.

Now the problem is when I change the language in my `PreferenceActivity` everything works just fine in every activity of my application the language changes (all string references and drawable references are correct). Only in my main activity the drawable references are always from the drawable-hr-hdpi folder. Why does it not change there? And the best part is that the string references on my main activity work correct too.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just call the `setContentView` again but in `onResume` for my main activity if there was a change in the language settings. I don't know if that is the correct way to do it but it works :)